# Adding small normally distributed random displacement to a pandas-based scatterplot

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

So I created a scatterplot based off of 2 dataframes. I'm trying to now add a small normally distributed random displacement to my X and Y so the points look better (very clustered right now).

```
normal_curve = np.random.normal(loc=mean_genders, scale=spread_genders, size=253)
```

Is what I have now, i'm not sure if im using this right. If i did this right, how do I implement it to my points?

Answer (score 2):

you can add normally distributed random displacement using `randn` as show below.

```
# some example data
x = np.arange(1,10, 0.1)
y = x**2

# pick a sigma and mu for normal distribution
sigma = 1
mu =0.01

# generate normally distributed samples
noise = sigma * np.random.randn(len(x)) + mu

# plot with original data points
plt.scatter(x,y, color = 'r')
# plot with normally distributed random displacement
plt.scatter(x+noise,y+noise, color = 'g')
```

this results in

[image]

Comment: I'm getting: ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (253,2) (253,) which I know is because of the X and Y have different shapes, that is because the Y has two types that are getting graphed together against X. Is there a way around this? or do I have to use the same dimensions.

Comment: instead of one scatter plot with y+noise, you can generate two more scatter plots but use y[:,0]+noise and y[:,1]+noise for y argument.

Comment: The problem is that I want all the data on one scatter plot

Comment: they will be on one figure, just that you use the command plt.scatter multiple times with different arguments.

Comment: plt.scatter(genders2,age) 
plt.scatter(genders2 + normal_curve,age[:,0] + normal_curve)
plt.scatter(genders2 + normal_curve,age[:,] + normal_curve)  for some reason now im getting error: ValueError: x and y must be the same size

Comment: Is there some difference between plt.scatter and plt.plot, because it seemed to have triggered this different message.

Comment: Can you try replacing age[:,] + normal_curve with age[:,1] + normal_curve

Comment: My mistake, didn't mean to do that but it's still giving me that error with that.

Comment: your are probably getting error from plt.scatter(genders2,age), because genders2 and age are different size. instead of this, use plt.scatter(genders2,age[:,0]) and plt.scatter(genders2,age[:,1])

Comment: I hope you were able to resolve your problem. Happy to help. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted.